# Saxon xquery validation fails - help needed to understand behavior

Tags: xquery, saxon, oxygenxml

Whilst i am using Saxon java api to execute the following xQuery, i am unable to understand why the following execution / validation fails ? (Interestingly , when i replace `and` clause with `or` in the if statement, the query validation is successful but am unable to understand this behaviour )

In oxygen xml validator, when i open the xQuery, i get `NullPointerException-null` exception and the validation fails.

And in java , i get the following area

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.markDependencies(LoopLifter.java:168)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:112)
```

I am looking up for some experts to help me understand why the following fails.

Following is the xQuery,

```
 
    declare function local:method($input as element(input)) as element(output) 
        {
                <output>
                    <itemADetails>              
                        <service>
                        {
                        for $i in 1 to count($input/*:foo)
                        return
                            for $j in 1 to count($input/*:bar)
                            return
                                if((data($input/*:foo[$i]/*:itemB[1]/*:rangeQualifier)="A") and (data($input/*:foo[$i]/*:serviceId/*:type)="B") ) then
                                    <node></node>
                                else()          
                        }
                        </service>                                          
                    </itemADetails>                                         
                </output>
        };


    declare variable $input as element(input) external;
    local:method($input)
```

### Saxon Verion

```
implementation 'net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:10.2'
implementation 'net.sf.saxon:saxon-xqj:9.1.0.8'
```

Sample Snippet that i tried

```
 Processor saxon = new Processor(false);
         
        // compile the query
        XQueryCompiler compiler = saxon.newXQueryCompiler();
        XQueryExecutable exec;
       
        ClassLoader classLoader = MessageProcessor.class.getClassLoader();
       
            exec = compiler.compile(new File(classLoader.getResource("Xquery.xqy").getFile()));

Source src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(Files.readString( Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(inputfile.xml").toURI()))));
        XdmNode doc = builder.build(src);
 // instantiate the query, bind the input and evaluate
        XQueryEvaluator query = exec.load();
        query.setContextItem(doc);     
 query.setExternalVariable(new QName("input"), doc.select(child("input")).asNode());
   XdmValue result = query.evaluate();
       System.out.println(result.itemAt(0).toString());
```

Irrespective of the java code when i open the xquery in Oxygen XML editor (that uses `Saxon-PE XQuery 9.9.1.7` engine) , i get the following validation error.

[image]

Comment: It always helps if you mention the exact version and edition of the software (e.g. Saxon) you use when you hit the problem. As you say you write Java code to use Saxon a minimal repro of that code would also be helpful.

Comment: Have updated my question with further details @MartinHonnen !

Comment: In the Java code, do you get the error on the `compiler.compile(new File(classLoader.getResource("Xquery.xqy").getFile()));` call or later on the `query.evaluate()` call? In the latter case, can you also include a minimal XML sample?

Comment: And please clarify, the code snippet you have shown uses `or`, the screenshot `and`? Does the problem occur with both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a Saxon optimisation bug. The problem occurs when Saxon attempts to rewrite

```
for $j in 1 to count($input/bar)
return if ($input/foo[$i]/data = 'A' and $input/baz[$i]/type = 'B')
       then <result/>
       else ()
```

as

```
if ($input/foo[$i]/data = 'A' and $input/baz[$i]/type = 'B')
then for $j in 1 to count($input/bar)
     return <result/>
else ()
```

and you can work around the problem by doing this rewrite "by hand". The purpose of the rewrite is to prevent the unnecessary repeated evaluation of the "if" condition, which is the same each time round the loop.

The reason it's dependent on the "and" condition is that Saxon considers each term of the "and" as a separate candidate for promoting outside the loop, and when it finds that all these terms can be promoted, it reconstitutes the "and" expression from its parts, and the bug occurs during this reconstitution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an optimizer bug in Saxon, I reduced your code to

```
declare function local:test($input as element(input)) as element(output)
{
  <output>
      <details>
          <service>
          {
              for $i in 1 to count($input/foo)
              return
                  for $j in 1 to count($input/bar)
                  return if ($input/foo[$i]/data = 'A' and $input/baz[$i]/type = 'B')
                         then <result/>
                         else ()
          }
          </service>
      </details>
  </output>
};

declare variable $input as element(input) external := <input>
</input>;

local:test($input)
```

and Saxon HE 10.2 from the command line crashes with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.markDependencies(LoopLifter.java:168)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:112)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:122)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.gatherInfo(LoopLifter.java:101)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.LoopLifter.process(LoopLifter.java:51)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryFunction.optimize(XQueryFunction.java:452)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryFunctionLibrary.optimizeGlobalFunctions(XQueryFunctionLibrary.java:327)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryModule.optimizeGlobalFunctions(QueryModule.java:1207)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Executable.fixupQueryModules(Executable.java:458)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.makeXQueryExpression(XQueryParser.java:177)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:568)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:630)
        at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryCompiler.compile(XQueryCompiler.java:609)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.compileQuery(Query.java:804)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.doQuery(Query.java:317)
        at net.sf.saxon.Query.main(Query.java:97)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think on the command line you can turn off optimization with `-opt:0`, then the above code doesn't crash.

You might want to raise your bug as an issue on https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/issues or wait until someone from Saxonica picks it up here.

If I use

```
           for $foo at $i in $input/foo
          return
              for $bar at $j in $input/bar
```

Saxon doesn't crash, so perhaps that is a way to rewrite your query as a workaround, although, without data, I am not quite sure I have captured the meaning of your code and that rewrite does the same as your original attempt.

Comment: Thank you Martin & @michael-kay , your answers were very helpful !!  As of now i have split the if clause into seperate statements ```if ($input/foo[$i]/data = 'A' and $input/baz[$i]/type = 'B')``` as ```if ($input/foo[$i]/data = 'A') then if ($input/baz[$i]/type = 'B')``` and got the expected results. However , I wish we get the expected result without changing the xquery by hand :)

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced it with Martin's test case (thank you, Martin): https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4765